# OpenCV - store camera matrix and distortion coefficients as Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, camera-calibration

I've used the sample OpenCV program to calculate the camera matrix and distortion coefficients from my camera and produced an xml file with the relevant data.

I'm trying to use it through the `undistort` function but I'm not sure how to store the values as a `Mat`.

```
Mat cameraMatrix;
Mat distortionCoefficients;
undistort(image, newImage, cameraMatrix, distortionCoefficients);
```

I've tried:

```
Mat cameraMatrix = 1.7514028018776246e+03 0. 1.2635000000000000e+03 0. 1.7514028018776246e+03 9.2750000000000000e+02 0. 0. 1.;
Mat distortionCoefficients = 1.3287735059062630e-01 -6.8376776294978103e-01 0. 0. 8.1215478360827675e-01;
```

Do I need to try and specify a series of rows and columns to the `Mat` var and then assign each value an index?

Comment: So you need to know how to create a matrix with some values? Or how to load a matrix from the xml?

Comment: I just need to know how to apply these values to their respective variables to use in the `undistort` function. The first method would suffice.

Comment: Check [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistort) and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) for the order of parameters (if you still haven't). Then you can create a matrix like: `Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat1d(3, 3) << fx, 0, cx, 0, fx, cx, 0, 0, 1);`

Comment: Thanks, what parameters in place of `(3,3)`do I need to provide for the `distortionCoefficients`?

Comment: `(1, N)`, where `N` is 4, 5, or 8

Comment: Thanks, if you like to put your comments as an answer I'd accept.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can see on OpenCV documentation for [undistort](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistort) that:

**Camera matrix** is a 3x3 matrix:

```
 fx   0  cx
  0  fy  cy
  0   0   1
```

that you can create as:

```
Mat cameraMatrix = (Mat1d(3, 3) << fx, 0, cx, 0, fy, cy, 0, 0, 1);
```

**distortionCoefficients** is a vector or 4, 5, or 8 parameters:

```
k1, k2, p1, p2 [, k3 [, k4, k5, k6]]
```

that you can create as:

```
Mat distortionCoefficients = (Mat1d(1, 4) << k1, k2, p1, p2);
Mat distortionCoefficients = (Mat1d(1, 5) << k1, k2, p1, p2, k3);
Mat distortionCoefficients = (Mat1d(1, 8) << k1, k2, p1, p2, k3, k4, k5, k6);
```

You can find the meaning of the parameters on [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)