# How to translate lense undistortion from Lens Distortion Model to opencv?

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, opencv3.0, distortion

So [OpenCV undistort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023303/opencv-store-camera-matrix-and-distortion-coefficients-as-mat/34024057#34024057) takes as arguments two arrays `double k[6], p[2];` yet it is complicated to set them up when you do not have access to camera (only to its frames). There is an [algorithm called *Algebraic Lens Distortion Model Estimation*](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/ags-alde/) that takes in a picture and hand drawn lines on a frame and produces an [undistorted image](http://demo.ipol.im/demo/ags_algebraic_lens_distortion_estimation/archive/?key=1C3EFA932C69EE5A1254458F6F9F2B87). 
Its output may look like this:

> (Emin, Vmin, D) = (9.7709e+05, 8.3106e+00, 8.2942e+00)
>
> Distortion parameters: k[0] = 8.549082532748524e-01 k[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023303/opencv-store-camera-matrix-and-distortion-coefficients-as-mat/34024057#34024057) =
>   0.000000000000000e+00 k[2](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2011/ags-alde/) = 3.217447043912507e-08 k[3](http://demo.ipol.im/demo/ags_algebraic_lens_distortion_estimation/archive/?key=1C3EFA932C69EE5A1254458F6F9F2B87) = 0.000000000000000e+00 k[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3p92.png) = 1.407606498960670e-12
>
> Center of distortion (x0,y0) = (655.091196, 385.002911)

So we are given 5 items from `k` array and none from `p`. And I see no mentionang of `p` in their article. So I wonder how to map their output to opencv?

---

A code sample that does not work for [this images](http://demo.ipol.im/demo/ags_algebraic_lens_distortion_estimation/archive/?key=1C3EFA932C69EE5A1254458F6F9F2B87):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/world.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Mat result;
    auto in = imread("test.png"); // http://demo.ipol.im/demo/ags_algebraic_lens_distortion_estimation/archive/?key=1C3EFA932C69EE5A1254458F6F9F2B87
    int fov = 60;
    //Center of distortion (x0,y0)
    auto x = 640.000000;
    auto y = 360.000000;
    // http://answers.opencv.org/question/17076/conversion-focal-distance-from-mm-to-pixels/?answer=17180#post-id-17180
    auto focalLengthX = x / tan(fov * 0.5 * acos(-1) / 180.0);
    auto focalLengthY = y / tan(fov* 0.5 * acos(-1) / 180.0);
    cv::Mat camera_matrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(3, 3) << focalLengthX, 0, x, 0, focalLengthX, y, 0, 0, 1);

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34024057/1973207 
    double k[5];
    k[0] = 8.648648537891959e-01;
    k[1] = 0.000000000000000e+00;
    k[2] = 8.319218976751903e-08;
    k[3] = 0.000000000000000e+00;
    k[4] = 9.568850206942498e-13;
    Mat distortionCoefficients = (Mat1d(1, 8) << k[0], k[1], 0, 0, k[2], k[3], k[4], 0);

    undistort(in, result, camera_matrix, distortionCoefficients);
    imshow("test", result);
    waitKey();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

It results in:

[image]

instead of desired:
[image]

---

As suggested negating `k[0]` gives:[image]

Comment: they use another distortion model for camera lenses, do they?

Answer (score 0):

From fastreading the paper, they propose a new way to determine the radial distortion. That are the k_N parameters.
tangential distortion are p parameters and not considered there.

Please try out, to set the p1 = 0 and p2 = 0, the resulting vector should be:

k1, k2, 0, 0, k3, k4 ...
If the paper proposes a completly different distortion model for cameras, it will not work.

http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/parameters.html
the distortion parameters should be the same as in opencv. kc(3) and kc(4) are p1 and p2

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calculating the tangential factors, this method finds the corrected center. Running the ANSI C program provided and beginning with the assumption that the center is at the mid point of the image, the program finds the true center. The original estimate is 344,253 and the corrected center is 347,259. Knowing the corrected center would seem to eliminate the necessity of applying tangential corrections.